# Jordan measurability of "Area under the curve" of a function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration, measurable-sets

Let $I = [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a riemann integrable function on $I$. Consider the set $S_f$ given by, $$S_f = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x \in I, 0 \leq y \leq f(x) \}$$
I want to prove that $S_f$ is a jordan measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I proved the result under the assumption that $f$ is continuous using the uniform continuity (and the fact that a set $X$ is jordan measurable iff its boundary $\partial X$ has measure $0$). But with Riemann integrability instead of continuity, I no more have the nice bounds that uniform continuity gives to contain the boundary in rectangles with arbitrarily small total area. Any help/solution is highly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can use that Riemann integrability gives you that the differences (upper sum) - (lower sum) can be arbitrarily small, and you can show that this is where (the hard part of) the boundary of $S_f$ is contained

Comment: what do you mean by "where (the hard part of) the boundary of $S_f$ is contained". Anyway, It would be really great if you write an answer. @Keshav

Comment: If $I= [a,b]$ say, then I think the boundary of the set is: the vertical sides at $a,b$, the horizontal part that lies along the $x$-axis ($y=0$), and the (hard) part which is basically the graph of the function $f$.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes the other part can quite trivially be contained in a rectangle of arbitrarily small size.

Comment: @mathematics_2001: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3435936/148510) may be helpful.

Comment: @RRL Thanks! it is helpful.